# Convert a varchar variable to a datetime variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I have a data with a few columns. One of them (Col1) is a varchar variable.

I'll give a sample of a few values :

```
 Col1:
 '2013-01-01 00:00:00:000'
 NULL
'2013-01-01 00:00:00:000'
```

I'n the design I'm trying to change the data type from a varchar variable into  a datetime variable and it throws me an error:

```
 "Unable to modify table. conversion failed when converting date and/or time from a character string".
```

Any suggestions to remove the problem?

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: you must have bad data

Comment: Maybe something like this helps you:

 SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2013-01-01 00:00:00:000')

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126805/2451726)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the varchar to datetime. You can use cast or convert function. You should store your date value in a proper format in your varchar column.

I assume you are using SQL server 2012.

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @d TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @d
VALUES ('2013-01-01 00:00:00:000')
    ,(NULL)
    ,('2013-01-01 00:00:00:000')

SELECT convert(DATETIME, Col1) AS DATE
```

In case the above query returns error then you can use try_convert function.
(this would ignore your bad format data) Note: You should take necessary action to your bad data.

```
SELECT try_convert(DATETIME, Col1) AS DATE
FROM @d
FROM @d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ISDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) to filter the date columns and simply `CAST` the column.

In the MSDN it describes as

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.

Sample execution with given data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @TestTable (Col1) VALUES 
('2013-01-01 00:00:00:000'),
(NULL),
('2013-01-01 00:00:00:000');

SELECT CAST(Col1 AS DATETIME)
FROM @TestTable
WHERE ISDATE(Col1) = 1
```

Output:

```
Col1
------------------------
2013-01-01 00:00:00:000
2013-01-01 00:00:00:000
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Jordan1200 as suggested above the following should be a quick and simple fix;

```
CAST(Col1 AS DATETIME) AS Col1
```

Comment: Edit - I fixed it.
{
It keeps throwing me the error. I noticed that the data doesn't recognize the null as a 'NULL' nor as '' and I can't extract only the null value in col1. Is somebody knows why?}

Comment: This seems strange @Jordan1200.

I've just taken a look at some of my intermediate views where I carry out my ETL and there are definitely columns which were previously of the data type 'varchar (120)' which I have gone on to cast as 'DATE'.

The same column also definitely contains Null values.

Sorry I can't be of anymore immediate help. I'll have a think.